# Django TypeError __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need help.
I am noob :).
I need to create Model in Django to save username and password.
User name is OK.
But password has problem.
**str** returned non-string (type tuple)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, default='User')
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='1234')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name, self.user_password
```

Comment: Why do you override `__str__` here?

Comment: `return self.user_name + ", " + self.user_password`

Answer (score 6):

As the error already says, a `__str__` needs to return a string, not a tuple. You can for example return:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, default='User')
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='1234')

    def __str__(self):
        # danger: might expose the password
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.user_name, self.user_password)
```

But that being said, it is *very* strange to add the password to the `__str__` object, since that would mean that if you render the `User`, you expose the password. It thus might be a better idea to just return the `user_name`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, default='User')
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='1234')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

It is also strange to save the password in a raw format. Usually the password is *hashed*.

If you want to change the user model, you should inherit from [**`AbstractUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser). For more see the [Django documentation on *Substituting a custom User model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: I understand ....Its only for my home usage.... security is not important.

Comment: And can u show me how can be models.py and how to save username and password in views.py to variables? thanks...I am newbie in python and Django. Thanks

Comment: @rasto009d: one usually works with `ModelForm`s for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/